# How can remove this script "/vendor/composer/installed.js" in laravel 5

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I don't know why is add this script **installed.js** by default on my web pages. How can I remove this script please suggest me?

thanks for advance.

[image]

Comment: Does any solution work?

Answer (score 1):

It happened to my every laravel projects which was uploaded in root directory? You have to know it not affected to which that are uploaded to subfolders.

**Try solution:**
There is malware files in vendor/composer folder you need to delete those
files.

Comment: to be specific, the files you're looking for most likely does not exist in the original code and has a different timestamp from the rest. at least that was my case.

Answer (score 1):

Your laravel code is malware affected when i checked your website, and checked that installed.js script it seems to be a cryptocurrency miner mallware file, might be located somewhere within your project or may be your hosting company is mallware affected, check your code first and check all your vendor used may be any of your vendor is affected which might be causing this issue, since that JS file contains links to `coinhive.com` i hope this help.